# Is this formula for $\zeta(2n+1)$ correct or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Tags: integration, riemann-zeta

I am calculating $\zeta(3)$ from this [formula](http://oeis.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Riemann_zeta_function_for_nonnegative_odd_integers):

$$\zeta(2n+1)=\frac{1}{(2n)!}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{2n}}{e^t -1}dt$$

From Grapher.app, I get $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{e^x -1}dx = .4318$ approximately which, when multiplied by $\frac{1}{2}$, does not give me the known value of $\zeta(3)$.

In Grapher.app I entered the integrand with variable $x$ instead of $t$. Does that make a difference here?

Is the formula correct or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computing the integral with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20x%5E2%20/%20%28e%5Ex%20-%201%29%20from%200%20to%201000) on a truncated interval (I chose $[0, 10000]$) gives $2.40411$, which is just about the correct answer. It would appear to be an issue in the application you're using.

Comment: I see...! I tried the same equation with the entire interval on WA, but it gave me the "Computation Time Exceeded" message. Now I know how to get around that. Thanks!

Comment: @zeta Sure; especially for a function with exponential decay like this one, it's pretty safe to truncate the interval a lot. In fact, cutting the integration off at $20$ gives the same result to $5$ decimal places.